# How to sort tabs in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, tab

[image]Please suggest how to sort tabs dynamically using index or number.

One idea is to use dynamic components  and add child using logic in controller. But I dont want to go with this idea.

I added the image. For example : we have 3 tabs named 1 ,2 and 3 . When I click on reorder they should be reorder in position like 3,1,2 using custom logic.

Comment: What tabs do you mean?

Comment: visualforce  component apex:tab i mean

Comment: Piyush, maybe this question will attract more answers if you elaborate more on what problem you're trying to solve ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke I added a image. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is described in http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm, in the section on childnodes.  With childnodes, you can dynamically add tabs to your tab panel.

Admittedly, it will be a lot of code--much more code than say, generating the page markup and returning it, but with the childnodes will retain ultimate flexibility for reordering your tabs.